# "don't know how to make .gitignore"

Tags: makefile, freebsd, openvpn

We are trying to install openvpn 2.3.5 on freeBSD. Build collapses with : "don't know how to make .gitignore".

There's very little I could find on the subject. 
The relevant lines that reference the file name are here:

Line 458:

```
dist_noinst_DATA = .gitignore .gitattributes config-version.h.in PORTS \
README.IPv6 TODO.IPv6 README.polarssl openvpn.sln msvc-env.bat \
msvc-dev.bat msvc-build.bat $(am__append_2)
```

and

Line 191

```
am__dist_noinst_DATA_DIST = .gitignore .gitattributes \
config-version.h.in PORTS README.IPv6 TODO.IPv6 \
README.polarssl openvpn.sln msvc-env.bat msvc-dev.bat \
msvc-build.bat INSTALL-win32.txt
```

Anybody out there have this issue? What might be the cause?

Comment: `"don't know how to make .gitignore".` is an error from make when it has been told to create a file that is has no recipe for (and so it cannot create it).

I'm not familiar enough with the autotool suite to know whether including those git metadata files in those lines is the correct thing to do or not but the issue is that for some reason that (or those) files are being given to make as something that it needs to create and it doesn't know how.

Comment: Thanks, I get a little clearer picture of whats going on. From what we understand it's trying to make some .gitignore files, and isn't able to figure it out. All i've been able to find online is the .gitignore files on openvpn, not how make deals with them.

Comment: make shouldn't be dealing with them at all, they aren't build related. They are version control related. They probably don't belong in those two lists to begin with.

Comment: That's what i first thought, but the .gitignore files don't even exist in the source package. It seems that Make is trying to create them, but for what reason is beyond me. It does stop the build process, which is why i care... :(

Comment: Right, those files should only exist when using a git checkout. Not in a source tarball. I think the inclusion of those files in those two lists is simply incorrect and broken. I would file a ticket with openvpn about this. I expect that if you were to try to build from a git checkout it would work (as they would exist).

Answer (score 2):

Are you installing OpenVPN from source?

The intended way to install from source is to compile a port (`make -C /usr/ports/security/openvpn install clean`).

Or you can just install a binary package: `pkg install openvpn`.

More information on installing software on FreeBSD: https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/ports.html

Comment: The intended deployment machine is actually pfsense build off free BSD 8.3. Is this method you suggest effective in this situation?

Comment: For 8.3 you'll need to run `pkg_add -r openvpn` to install it as binary package. As for compiling, the command line does not differ from one in the answer.